terraform dynamic block for openai
I am trying to achieve a use case where we have to deploy 2 different openAI model with single azurerm_cognitive_deployment block using for_each.
resource "azurerm_cognitive_deployment" "openai-model" {
  for_each              = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI
  provider              = azurerm.sub_openai_landing_zone
  name                  = each.value.name
  cognitive_account_id  = azurerm_cognitive_account.openAI[each.key].id
  model {
    dynamic "origin" {
        for_each = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.models
        content {
                format  = each.value.models.format
                name    = each.value.models.model_name
                version = each.value.models.version
            }
            scale {
                type     = "Standard"
                capacity = each.value.models.capacity
            }
        }
    }        
}

the var file.
openai_landing_zone_openAI = {
    "demo-openai" = {
        location              = "west us",
        rg_name               = "demo-rg",
        kind                  = "OpenAI",
        sku_name              = "S0",
        public_access         = false,
        local_auth_enabled    = false,
        custom_subdomain_name = "demo-openai",
        name                  = "demo-deployment",
        models = {
            "0" =  {
                format            = "OpenAI",
                version           = "0613",
                model_name        = "gpt-35-turbo",
                capacity          = "20"
            },
            "1" = {
                format            = "OpenAI",
                version           = "0613",
                model_name        = "gpt-4",
                capacity          = "20"
            }        
        }    
    }
}

I have wrote this block but it is giving syntax error. Is it possible to do this with single block. Please suggest if there is any other way.

Can you try with format = origin.value.format and repeat the same for the rest of the arguments in the dynamic origin block?
